# Using RegEx, How to replace multiple occurrences of the same word with grouping and other pattern criteria

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to replace some specific word in comments in some VB.NET code using a find/replace GREP tool, which itself is using VB.NET regex matching rules.

For the sake of this example, lets say I have this (note that I don't want to change the code itself):

```
'*** This day is the day of all days
     '*** This day is the day of all days (there are 4 spaces at the start)
    Dim day as integer
    day=day+1
```

I would like this:

```
'*** This night is the night of all nights
     '*** This night is the night of all nights (there are 4 spaces at the start)
    Dim day as integer
    day=day+1
```

My regex is as follows:

(^\s*'.*)day(.*)

and I'm replacing it with:

$1night$2

This only finds the last occurrence of day, and replaces it with night, so I see this:

```
'*** this day is the day of all nights
​    '*** this day is the day of all nights
​    Dim day as integer
​    day=day+1
```

How to replace it so it looks like this:

```
'*** this night is the night of all nights
​    '*** this night is the night of all nights
​    Dim day as integer
​    day=day+1
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but I recommend two things: one is www.regex101.com for testing regexes, and another is this resource on how to exclude certain patterns using regex: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Comment: `^\s*'\*{3}.*(?'match'day).*` creates a named capture group called "match" but only matches the results in your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of the fact that VB .NET supports variable-length lookbehinds, which allows us to replace matches of `"day"` with `"night"` for matches of the following regular expression.

```
(?<='.*)\bday(?=s\b|\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VHT94o/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=   begin a positive lookbehind
  '    match a single quote
  .*   match zero or more characters other than line terminators
)      end the positive lookbehind
(?=    begin a positive lookahead
  s\b  match 's' followed by a word boundary
  |    or
  \b   match a word boundary
)      end the positive lookahead
```

As shown at the link, this matches `"day"` as indicated below.

```
'*** This day is the day of all days
          ^^^        ^^^        ^^^
'    *** This day is the day of all days
              ^^^        ^^^        ^^^
Dim day as integer 'so far so good today but maybe not another day
                                                               ^^^
day=day+1   'a daystar is a planet visible in the east before sunrise
```

All is not wine and roses, however.

```
text1.Text = "'day"   'No, no, not there!
               ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I provided a simplistic example, and used the word 'day' which is 'just a word', but you were too smart and found other examples of 'day' that could cause issues. The actual word I will be looking for is longer and very unique, so I don't think I'll run into other cases where it is being used. But it helped me figure out what I needed to do. Using your example and the one from The Fourth Bird above, I was able to arrive at a solution that was good enough for me.

Comment: I am tempted to respond to your last sentence by saying, "that's all that matters", but of course it's not. Whenever you learn something it will help you solve a problem in future or to learn something else (assuming you are not run over by a bus anytime soon).

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET you could use for example:

```
(?<!\S)(?<!\bDim\s+)day(s)?(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookabehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?<!\bDim\s+)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `Dim` followed by whitespace chars to the left
- `day(s)?`Match `day` and capture an optional `s` char
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a .NET [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/diW1vv/1).

In the replacement use:

```
night$1
```

The output will be:

```
'*** This night is the night of all nights
     '*** This night is the night of all nights (there are 4 spaces at the start)
    Dim day as integer
    day=day+1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I provided a simplistic example, and your solution, although not exactly what I wanted, helped me figure out what I needed to do. Specifically, I didn't want to include any of the specific code in the regex (in your provided solution, it had 'dim' hard coded into the regex). Using your example and the one from Cary below, I was able to arrive at a solution that was good enough.